# How to read all text files in a folder and filter display based on the suffix or prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use jQuery to read all text files in a folder and display their contents, but then, filter which should ones should be displayed based on the name of the folder.

**Here's the JavaScript:**

```
var obj = {
  "01600610/9874565214_789545621.txt": "",
  "01600610/9874565214_789545622.txt": "",
  "01600610/9874565214_789545623.txt": ""
};
$.each( obj, function(SavedText) {
  $.get(SavedText, function(data){
    $('#NewMessagesHolder').prepend('<div class="MessageClass">'+ '<span class="ChatName">' + CookieName + ' ('+ time + ')</span>' + ': '+ data +'</div>')
    }, 'text');
});
```

On this:

```
var obj = {
    "01600610/9874565214_789545621.txt": "",
    "01600610/9874565214_789545622.txt":"",
    "01600610/9874565214_789545623.txt":""
};
```

**Q1**: How do I get all text files inside a folder instead of specifying the file I want?

**Q2**: How can I filter? For example, how can I only get files ending or starting with 789545.

Comment: Best way would be to give an AJAX call, let your server iterate over actual folder, perform the logic of filtration and send back the data to your page.

Comment: Where are the files located?

Comment: Hi user3109875, could you expand on your problem, specifically, where are are the files located(server side, client side host OS, client side html5 file-system/sandbox, ect.) as well as what generated that javascript object you have listed above(was it a JSON from a HTTPResponse, something parsed and created with the assistance of the File-API, or something else)? This information would be especially helpful toward being able to fully answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When these files are on your local filesystem, you can use the [HTML5 Filesystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

If the files are located on a server, there is no way listing them from plain (client-side) javascript (maybe except a brute-force method, which shouldn't be considered of course). Then you have to write a server script (in PHP/Node/Perl/Phython/...) which will respond to a ajax request with a file list.

If you are using a server script, you should do the filtering on the server (so the answer depends on the language).
Otherwise you should use [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
var search = new RegExp("789545");
for(var file in obj) {
    if(search.test(file)) 
        alert(file+": "+obj[file]);
}
```

This would search for files with a name containing the pattern `789545`

Answer (score 0):

Please create index.php file and add this content to it. Create there a folder called "files" and add your files there

```
<?php
function contains($haystack, $needle){
    if (strpos($haystack,$needle) !== false) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
if(isset($_POST['get_files'])){
    $folder = "";
    $filter = "";
    if(isset($_POST['folder'])){
        $folder = $_POST['folder'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['filter'])){
        $filter = $_POST['filter'];
    }

    $files = array();
    foreach(glob($folder.'/*.*') as $filename){
        if($filter != ""){
            if(contains($filename, $filter)){
                $files[] = $filename;
            }
        }else{
            $files[] = $filename;
        }       
    }
    print_r($files);
    exit;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getData(){
    jQuery.post('index.php',{
        get_files:true,
        folder:"files",
        filter:""
    },function(data){
        jQuery('#container').html(data);
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Get data" onclick="getData();" />
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can specify different folder, and filename filter in jQuery post request call

Answer (score 0):

U can use regular expressions to filter the filenames. And for getting all files in a folder, U want to run a server side script. I use perl or php, to do this kinda stuff. U can use ajax to post the request and make the server script to return the file contents.

http://perlmeme.org/faqs/file_io/directory_listing.html
This link is just an example to do what u need in perl. And u could possibly do the same with other languages too